# Calculate total number of open item at each month in Powerpivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

I want to find a way to calculate the total amount of open items in each month in powerpivot. My data looks like this...

```
Id    Team    CreatedDate   ClosedDate   
01    AAA     1/30/2014     5/13/2014 
02    BBB     2/9/2014      2/18/2014 
03    CCC     5/10/2014     9/15/2014
```

Result should look like this...

```
Month     Count 
Jan2014   1
Feb2014   2
Mar2014   1
Apr2014   1
May2014   2
Jun2014   1
Jul2014   1
Aug2014   1
Sep2014   1
```

Is any way to do this?

TIA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a calculated column with the formula in PowerPivot below:

```
=IF([ClosedDate]>=TODAY(),"Open","Closed")
```

and count the number of "Open" strings.

Comment: I think that would assume that there is a close date entered. Although absent any other information from the OP, who knows?!